# Should I be using <form> instead of <table> here?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a collection of fields. These fields will need to be validated with Jquery. So that I can display an alert e.g. field is empty.  Then I will need to take the numbers entered into each field, & multiply them  etc, in php (to keep the formulas private) . Should I be using  `<form>` instead of `<table>` here?

```
<table class="no-top-border">
            <tr class="no-top-border">
                <td class="quarter-width field-label hide-mobile no-top-border">
                    <label for="material">Operation Type</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value no-top-border">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Operation Type</p>
                    <select name="is_robotic" id="is_robotic">
                        <option value="1">Robotic Welding</option>
                        <option value="0">Manual Welding</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>                           
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="number_of_welds">Number of Welds</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Number of Welds</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" id="number_of_welds" name="number_of_welds" class="calculator-field yellow-bg first-inputs" title="Enter number of welds" min="0" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="number_of_construction_welds">Number of Construction Welds</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Number of Construction Welds</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" id="number_of_construction_welds" name="number_of_construction_welds" class="calculator-field yellow-bg first-inputs" title="Enter number of construction welds" min="0" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <strong>Quantity of Parts to Load</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Under 1kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Under 1kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="load_weight_1" id="load_weight_1" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to load under 1 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Between 1kg and 8kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Between 1kg and 8kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="load_weight_2" id="load_weight_2" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to load between 1 kg and 8 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Between 8kg and 12kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Between 8kg and 12kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="load_weight_3" id="load_weight_3" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to load between 8 kg and 12 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <strong>Quantity of Parts to Unload</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Under 1kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Under 1kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="unload_weight_1" id="unload_weight_1" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to unload under 1 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Between 1kg and 8kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Between 1kg and 8kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="unload_weight_2" id="unload_weight_2" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to unload between 1 kg and 8 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="holes">Between 8kg and 12kg</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Between 8kg and 12kg</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="unload_weight_3" id="unload_weight_3" class="calculator-field green-bg first-inputs" title="Enter weight to unload between 8 kg and 12 kg" min="0" placeholder="(optional)" />
                    <p class="error-text"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="hide-mobile"></td>
                <td><button id="clear-button" class="btn-red">Clear all data</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="no-borders">
                <td colspan="2" class="no-borders"><hr></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="no-top-border">
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile no-top-border">
                    <strong>Outputs</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value no-top-border">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="loading_unloading">Loading / Unloading</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Loading / Unloading</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="loading_unloading" id="loading_unloading" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="calculator-field" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="robot_addr_in_out">Robot address in / out</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Robot address in / out</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="robot_addr_in_out" id="robot_addr_in_out" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="calculator-field" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="weld_time">Weld time</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Weld time</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="weld_time" id="weld_time" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="calculator-field" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="controlling_cycle">Controlling cycle</label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Controlling cycle</p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="controlling_cycle" id="controlling_cycle" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="calculator-field" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td class="field-label hide-mobile">
                    <label for="total_time">Total time <small>(secs)</small></label>
                </td>
                <td class="field-value">
                    <p class="show-mobile mobile-label">Total time <small>(secs)</small></p>
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="total_time" id="total_time" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="calculator-field" />
                </td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td class="hide-mobile"></td>
                <td><button id="spot-welding-calculate-button"  class="btn-blue">Calculate cycle time</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: If you want to be able to submit this data without JavaScript, you'll need to have a `<form>` in there. But you don't need to replace your `<table>`; just wrap it in a `<form>`. The `<table>` is there for *structure*, whereas the `<form>` is necessary for *functionality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `form` if you are transmitting data.

You can use a `table` inside a `form`.

By the way, I'll also recommend using `fieldset`, a nice element for fields.

Comment: I'm new to coding in general . I've seen a professional use table instead of form. Is this kind of mistake common for a professional? Thanks

Comment: @mattnewbie Yes, it is a common mistake. In fact, I recently put together [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569396/is-this-a-table/19569730#19569730), in which I describe the difference between the two. I would strongly suggest using what Ali Gajani said, which is you can use a `table` element inside of a `form`.

Comment: If you were planning on sending data to a backend, there is form. Tables and forms are different. Tables is more of a visible element whereas forms are designed for transmission and capturing of information.

Comment: @JaceCotton Interesting. I'm surprised by how many coding  mistakes professionals make!

Comment: @mattnewbie - The only difference between amateurs and professionals is that the professionals have found someone to pay them while they make their mistakes.

Comment: @Alohci - Haha, nice one. Those who pay professionals to make mistakes are amateurs :)

Answer (score 1):

For better semantic HTML. Use `<form>` instead of `<table>`

Comment: I've seen a professional using table rather than form. Is this a common mistake? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use table tag if you´re formatting a form or an entire site. Table is only for organizing Data.